# Asymptotic Behavior of Stochastic Differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I have system of three SDE's.  They have the following form:

$$dx=x(zF_1(x,z)-d)dt+\sigma_1 dW_1(t)$$
$$dy=y(zF_2(x,z)-d)dt+\sigma_2 dW(t)_2$$
$$dz=((x+y)d-z(xF_1(x,z)+yF_2(x,z)))dt+\sigma_3 dW_3(t)$$

Numerical integration(Euler-Maruyama ) seems to suggest that the fraction $\frac{x}{x+y}$ is increasing with respect to $\sigma_3$. I understand that these are highly non linear equations, but I was wondering if any body has has any ideas about how to approach the problem of the asymptotic behavior of it, especially in the case that $\lim\sigma_1,\sigma_2\to 0$

Also, x+y+z==1 by construction

Comment: In the last component $W_3$ is different from the $W$ in the first two components, and these Wiener processes are identical?

Comment: Hello. The three wiener processes are not the same. They are independent though. Is there some litelature that  i can go to for the stationary distribution of this system?

Comment: Then in the second equation it should also be $F_2$? So that when all $σ_k=0$, then $d(x+y+z)=0$?

Comment: Hello. I edited the question. Also, just to emphasize,  F1 and F2 are functions of x and z

Comment: You could remove $y$ for $σ_4W_4-x-z$ where $σ_4=\sqrt{σ_1^2+σ_2^2+σ_3^2}$ and $W_4=(σ_1W_1+σ_2W_2+σ_3W_3)/σ_4$ is another Wiener process, essentially replacing $W_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Does this come out from application of ito's lemma. Also, x+y+z==1. I am wondering if i can reduce it to a single SDE. Then i apply the results i  know from one dimensional ito processes

Comment: You got a point there, it should be $y=C+σ_4W_4−x−z$ to account for the initial conditions. If you want to make it complicated, you can use the Ito lemma. As it is, I just summed up the equations on both sides and observed that all $dt$ terms cancel. That $W_4$ is again a Brownian motion follows from general results about the arithmetic of BM.